# A bug in my simple python program of lcs

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
def lcs(i, j):
    global x, y, c         
    if i <= 0 or j <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if c[i][j] < 0:
            if x[i - 1] == y[j - 1]:
                c[i][j] = lcs(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            else:
                m = lcs(i - 1, j)
                n = lcs(i, j - 1)
                print m, n
                c[i][j] = max(m, n)
        else: return c[i][j]
c = np.zeros((8, 8), int)
c = c - 1
x = 'ABCBDAB'
y = 'BDCABA'
lcs(7, 6)
print c
```

the program has bugs so i lookup the 'm','n',

the print results come up with 'None'

ex:

```
0 0
0 None
0 None
0 None
None None
```

then the program occur an error:

```
TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

i don't know where the 'None' comes

i'm a newer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know where the 'None' comes

If you don't return anything, the return value of a python function is `None`.

In particular, you don't return anything in the `if c[i][j] < 0:` branch.